# How to deprecate/delete/garbage-collect event types on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase is limited to 500 event types per app.
Suppose I used 400 event types so far, out of which 300 are no longer needed, but I need to support 200 new ones. I would have liked to delete those 300 unused types, to "free up" quota for the new 200. I can't find a way for wiping out old/unused event types.
Any solution for freeing up event types quota?

Answer (score 0):

there currently is no direct solution to delete Analytic events once logged. However, a Firebase blog post covered potentially removing data associated with Analytics for user privacy. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/05/a-few-updates-on-privacy-and-security.html

It's not a solid solution, but it indicates that you can have some level of control over Analytics by deleting the user associated with the data, but it may not be related to analytic events directly which may leave the event types intact.

Another solution that people have found is to simply create a new project ID and migrate the data, but it's not a manageable solution.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9019185?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article